# Editable rows is not working in table with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, html

I parsed JSON objects and made a table structure to display the elements. I wanted to make rows of table editable. This is is the code i used to form the table.

```
    (jsonDatag.data).forEach(function(item) {
                    var _tr = '<tr class="' + item.symbol + '"><td>' + item.symbol + '</td><td class="' + hclass + '">' + item.highPrice + '</td><td class="' + lclass + '">' + item.lowPrice + '</td><td class="' + oclass + '">' + item.openPrice + '</td><td class="' + ltclass + '">' + item.ltp + '</td><td>' + item.previousPrice + '</td><td>' + item.lastCorpAnnouncementDate + '</td></tr>'
                _tbody += _tr
            });
            _thead = _thead + _tbody;
            $('.mytable').html(_thead)
        }
```

Now I added these lines to make my rows editable but it is not reflecting in my output.

```
                  $('tr.'+item.symbol+'').each(function() {
                $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

What is going wrong here and how can i correct it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Editable rows is not working in table

This seems to be confusing since it is the `td` which is editable.

Also this snippet

```
$('tr.' + item.symbol + '').each(function() {
  $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

probably will place an `input`.

If you are looking to make a editable `td` then

```
<td contenteditable="true">
```

will work

Comment: how are you setting it?

Comment: i tried hard coding it directly and  used the attr function to add it also both did not reflect

Comment: assign it to td inside forEach loop

Comment: But what if i want table to reflect the edited values after reloading also ? I have to do anything else ??

Comment: @Karthykn you have update the data source with new value  which is creating the table